# How do I write Regex for a SublimeText2 snippet that does both a replace and a slice?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext2, boost-regex

I've been looking at making more snippets for Sublimetext2. I've been looking at http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html and other questions here and I was able to write this snippet to get the name of the file as a function name:

```
<content><![CDATA[function ${1:${TM_FILENAME/(.+)\..+|.*/$1/:name}$SELECTION()
{

}]]></content>
```

But now I am trying to write one that takes TM_FILEPATH does a replace and slices of the filename and the beginning of the path. For example I want to turn this:

```
"/Library/WebServer/Documents/projects/CGI/source/com/test/play/Bla.js"
```

into this:

```
"com.test.play"
```

I am stumped by the regex syntax and what I should do with "${var_name/regex/format_string/options}". Can anyone explain to me how to write such a regex, and how to use these four items to rewrite the TM_FILEPATH variable?

Comment: You will need 2 steps, one to capture the `com/test/play`, and the other to change the `/` to `.`. Just in case the namespace has more levels or less than 3. Not sure if they allow you to pass in another level of replacement in the replace string.

Comment: Is it possible to do two steps in a single regex? I tried looking for other ways to hook into the snippet being inserted, but it seems there isn't any.

Comment: It is possible if you limit the number of levels. Another thing I didn't mention is that, you need to know where the start of the namespace is - is "source" always the folder before the start of namespace?

Comment: Yes, source is always going to be the start.

Comment: When I tried to do this, I realized that I still need 2 steps regardless. The thing is, I need to know the number of levels to insert the `.` correctly.